# Countable elementary sub-structure of the automorphism group of the binary rooted tree

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the automorphism group of the binary rooted tree.

The [downward Löwenheim-Skolem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) theorem states that G has a countable elementary sub-structure.

My question is whether such sub-structure is explicitly known?

Comment: Is this a complete & infinite binary rooted tree?  There's a nice description of how to construct these automorphisms in the Wikipedia article on the Grigorchuk group here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group#Definition

Comment: This is a finitely-generated, infinite, nilpotent automorphism group.